# Seat selection layout like redbus

Tags: java, android

I'm working on a bus ticket reservation app, I have no idea how to do the seat selection like in redbus app, can anyone please help me out? Any suggestion or sample code or anything?

Comment: You can use recyclerview.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: i need suggestion how to do it, or any referal link if you have..